# Keeping stripe's uncaptured payment for more than 7 days

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

**My problem:**

Currently in my project it's required to keep a payment in an uncaptured state for more than 7 days which is the maximum for stripe.

**What I came up with atm:**

I see that it can be done by remembering customer's card (using stripe's api for this of course), creating an uncaptured payment, refunding it when the 7-day period comes to an end and creating it again until we choose to finally capture it.

I guess this 'hack' will be used only once per a payment as usually we have to hold the payment for about 10 days.

**Questions:**

1. Are there any pitfalls besides that a customer will see a second payment?
2. Any other ways to handle this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'd probably avoid holding it for 7+ days to be honest.  Especially because it's not a guarantee that the charge will fall of the customer's card at the end of that 7-day period immediately.  The authorization might fall off 3-5 days after the fact.  This could mean that if you're holding $300.00, then there could be a time period of up to 3-5 days where a user may be out $600.00 (ie. 2x $300.00 auth).  I can't imagine your users would enjoy this experience.  Instead, I'd hold a deposit or change the holding period.

Comment: Hm, I see. That can be an issue for sure, I'm going to reach out to stripe support to confirm it. Maybe releasing the authorization does not take as long as refunding a confirmed payment.

Comment: @korben, I'll accept your answer if you post it below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we ended up sticking to this method described in the question, but @korben's point is true, it's still hard to handle because even if a bank can release the funds fast, we still don't know when exactly does it happen as stripe can't inform us when the customer actually got his money back whether it's two minutes or two days.

It still works for us, because the payment is not that big and happens in person, so customers can choose whether they want to give a deposit in cash or use this method which seems more comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

For context (because I was recently solving this problem and came across this thread), a number of websites recommend if you have a payment that wasn't captured within seven days, then cancel the order and create a new one. For example, Shopify recommends this and the authorization expiry date is displayed on the Orders page.

However, for all of the reasons @korben mentioned, it's best practise to avoid holding authorizations for over 7 days. Additional fees are also charged when collecting charges after the standard authorization period (depending on the issuing bank of a credit card).